# how to work out percentage of something which adds to 80%

Tags: percentages

I have a problem I can't workout.

I have 3 work streams

maintenance
optimisation
innovation

I know I'm going to spend $20\%$ of my time on maintenance but don't have any specifics line items I know I will spend $4$ units of time work on optimisation and $2$ units work on innovation.

Is there a way to work out what percentage of work I will do on Optimisation and Innovation?

to clarify M + O + I = 100% M = 20%

so         O + I = 80%  O=? and I =?

Comment: $2$ units = $20$%, can you calculate how many units for $100$%?

Comment: 2 units of time work on maintenance is 20% of your time. So, 1 unit of time work is 10% of your time. Can you pick it up from here? :)

Comment: @cr001 if 2 units = 20% then M = 20% O = 20% and I = 40 this is 80% i'm trying to find what O and I are that add to 80%

Comment: @OmarS f 2 units = 20% then M = 20% O = 20% and I = 40 this is 80% i'm trying to find what O and I are that add to 80%

Comment: In the question, it is mentioned that 4 units of time work is spent on optimization. Hence, O= 40%. Finally, you are left with 20% and I.

Comment: @OmarS sorry made a typo a put maintenance rather than Optimisation. I know units of time for I and O but not for M. But i no percentage of time for M but not I and O.

Comment: I think the solution is pretty clear now. Good luck and best wishes to you!